# OpenGL Depth Buffer Problem

Tags: opengl, graphics, depth-buffer, vertex-buffer

For my last few projects I have been using some of the utility files that I found whilst looking at a few demos [here](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/glslTerrainTexturing.html).

Namely a file called opengl.h - mainly used to manage shaders a bit like glew and another file gl_font.

gl_font is a class they use to render fonts on screen using vertex buffer objects.

However, when I use this to render the framerate in my game it draws everything but the skybox correctly.  For some reason the skybox is rendered white as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqlfd.png), if I do not render the font it looks like [this](http://www.henryprescott.com/images/stackoverflow/problem2.png).

Here are some parts of the gl_font class that I think are most important:

```
void GLFont::begin()
{
    HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    RECT rcClient;

    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    int w = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
    int h = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;

    glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fontTexture);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, w, h, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);

    drawTextBegin();
}
```

I have trie changing `glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT);` to glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_BIT); and the background texture returns, but the font isn't rendered.

```
void GLFont::end()
{
    drawTextEnd();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPopAttrib();
}
```

[This](http://www.henryprescott.com/images/stackoverflow/problem3.png) is an image of the depth buffer when the font is rendered and [this](http://www.henryprescott.com/images/stackoverflow/problem4.png) is what is looks like when it is not.

Could anyone shed some light on this problem please?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `begin()` lacks a `glPushMatrix()` after `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`. This might cause the scene to be rendered incorrectly when some text is also rendered.

Didn't `glGetError()` report a `GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW` error?

Comment: I'm rendering the text last, so the pushmatrix shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Depends if you create modelview from scratch per frame. Anyway: if you have `GL_LIGHTING_BIT` also present in `glPopMatrix` and you draw the text last, are you sure that it passes depth test? Have you tried disabling GL_DEPTH_TEST for the time of rendering text?

Comment: @DeadMG, </propaganda>. They've already cleared that mess in recent API, there's nothing to complain about in GL 3 and GL 4... I guess :)

Comment: @DeadMG, and too bad that all those stubborn CAD software engineers use OpenGL anyway, despite it's horrifying PushMatrices! (And *why* are we continuing this holy war...? We have a Question to answer here!)

Comment: @Kos: This isn't about OGL vs D3D, it's about that the very idea of PushMatrix *sucks* and should never even have been considered.

Comment: @DeadMG, The only thing which sucks is that it was part of the OGL API itself. It's quite a natural tool for implementing a scene tree.

Comment: I am resetting the matrix each frame.  I have tried disabling depth test, it does nothing.

Comment: @henryprescott - okay... in that case, please prepare a scene with just the skybox and text (invisible) and append a GLintercept frame log to your question - it'll be easier to diagnose it in that way I think.

Comment: I decided just to go with FTGL it doesn't have VBOs but I have it working fine.